# Future value formula not working properly. Answer is very big number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Excel incorrect calculation of FV]

Please let me know if I am missing anything here.
When I used some other online calculator i got the correct expected answer. As shown in the below image.

[image: Correct calculation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an integer "7" in the 1st parameter is the same as an interest of "700%". Hence your huge number. You need to either reference a true percentage or enter it directly in this parameter ("7%" or "0.07"). Use:

```
=FV(7%,25,5000,0,1)
```

Note that I used a "1" in the last parameter to indicate payments are due at the beginning of each period (as per your requirements in the screenshot).